# How do I use Haskell (hugs)?

Tags: 10.10, programming, haskell

Hey!
I have installed hugs on Ubuntu 10.10
But now I have the problem how to run it.
Before, I mean in later versions of Ubuntu I typed just sudo run hugs and it worked. Now it doesnt work.

How should I run hugs in Ubuntu 10.10?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run an interactive haskell interpreter with the `hugs` command or you can execute a haskell program in a file with the `runhugs` command - to execute a file called `file.hs`, enter `runhugs file.hs`.

eg.

[image]

Here I created a simple hello world program (You will probably want to use an actual text editor like Gedit for this; I used `cat` cause I'm l33t) then tried to run it with `hugs` but realised that this only launched the interactive session .

This may be very useful for you (and it has wonderful ASCII art) but I wanted to execute my haskell file so I consulted [the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/hugs) of `hugs` and found that I needed to use `runhugs` for this. When I used the `runhugs` command it executed my program and printed a "Hello, World!" message.

**PS**

Why were you using `sudo run hugs`? There is no command called `run` and using `sudo` to run a programming environment could be very dangerous - it allows you to do *anything* to your system. Only use `sudo` when absolutely necessary.

Comment: oh...wait. I am a new one in Ubuntu. So, to run haskell I need to type in terminal the runhugs ...(the place where my haskell programms are stored and the name of them file).hs  it doesnt work as well.It tells me "error-undefined variable "main"", even though I dont have such a variablen in my haskell code